# Как сделать .EXE файл с игрой на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, exe

Я написал игру на языке Python 3 в PyCharm с помощью библиотеки tkinter. Мне нужно эту игру перевести в .exe файл, чтобы я мог скинуть другу и он смог бы в неё поиграть. Нужно учитывать, что в игре использованы картинки, то есть, мне нужно не только один файл .py перевести в .exe , а ещё и картинки с этим файлом
Возможно в PyCharm есть такая функция, которая переводит в .exe файл, но я об такой не слышал.

Comment: попробуйте использовать PyInstaller

Comment: https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: Игровые ресурсы (картинки, аудио и т.д.) не зашиваются в exe.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью PyInstaller пробовали?

https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/

На сколько мне известно он собирает .py в .exe вместе с изображениями.

Comment: Пробовал через pyinstaller сделать, вот ошибка: ValueError: script 'D:\Zmeika\snake.py' not found D - локальный диск. "Zmeika" - папка в которой файл. "snake.py" - сам файл.

Comment: А как именно вы это делали? Можете показать ход своих действий? Для начала через cmd нужно перейти в директорию с файлом, после пишите команду Допустим у меня игра на диске C: Пишем: cd C:\ Далее пишем pyinstaller названиефайла.py

Comment: Я эту проблему уже решил. У меня новая проблема. У меня игра с картинками, когда я её конвертирую и запускаю, на пару секунд открывается консоль и выключается. Я пробовал кидать папку с картинками к файлу, должно работать, но нет. А программы которые одним файлом, вроде все конвертируются.

Answer (score 1):

pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz
Лучше качать с исходников, т.к. он шалит в python 3.8.0

Comment: Я ввел это в командную строку, но мне это не помогла, всё равно выдает ошибку
ValueError: script 'D:\Zmeika\snake.py' not found D - локальный диск. "Zmeika" - папка в которой файл. "snake.py" - сам файл.

Comment: Я ввожу путь без кавычек. У меня работает. Попробуйте ещё раз)

Comment: Получилось?????

Comment: Я нигде никаких кавычек не ставил при вводе, это только для комментария, чтобы выделить нужное. А по поводу получилось, я много там чего-то натыкал, в общем,  получается конвертировать только файл без картинок, а файл где нужны картинки, не открывается, я даже папку с адресом кидал туда, где файл, по-идеи должен работать, но нет. Ну, короче, проблема не решена, нужно конвертировать файл с картинками.

Comment: И программа у меня написана на 3.7, хотя на компьютере у меня установлена 3.8 и 3.7. Проверил, все pip файлы устанавливаются на 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

Сначало чекни видео
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgCJwDjm_Cw
в коде укажи не полный путь, а текущую директорию
и скидывай не EXE файл а архив с экзешником и прилагающимися к нему файлами

Answer (score 0):

Сначала в CMD: `pip install pyinstaller`
Потом переходишь в директорию игры, где главный файл.
Потом делаешь примерно: `pyinstaller main_file.(py/pyw) --onefile`
Новые версии `pyinstaller` реагируют на `.pyw` и добавляют флаг `--noconsole`.
`pyinstaller` тебе генерирует `EXE`-шник в папку `dist`, которую он создает.
Вы перемещаете `EXE`-шник из `dist` в папку где он был раньше.
Там он уже достает изображения. `pyinstaller` же не запаковывает всю папку в `EXE`-шник!

У меня так всегда все работало!